# Расширение для гуглХром, которое примет данные с компа и вставит в поля на сайте

Tags: google-chrome, расширения

Возможно ли написать расширение для хром, которое будет ожидать от моей программы на java данные, которые впишутся в формы на открытом сайте (отсылать данные, слать запрос не требуется). Да или хотя бы пусть не ждет данные, а имеет возможность загрузить их с жесткого диска, чтобы вставить в формы сайта. 
Возможно ли? 
В какую сторону копать? Ну как не веб программисту, как человеку который знает только Java, дайте направление, чтобы я мог попробовать написать это расширение.

Comment: невозможно. ваше приложение на java должно быть само http сервером, что бы расширение chrome могло к нему подключиться как к обычному сайту и получить данные как с обычного сайта

Comment: А сможет ли расширение считывать с жесткого диска? Просто мне нужен способ заполнить  формы сайта, проверить их. и самому нажать сохранить.

Comment: ну или хотя бы могу ли я вставить в это расширение из буфера обмена данные, чтобы он их расфасовал по формам сайта?

Comment: Ну это да, открываете скажем popup и в нем поле для ввода данных

Comment: Хотя с диска наверное то же можно, создаете новую вкладку и задаете url `file://C:/...` наверное прокатит, а может безопасность браузера не позволит, проверять надо